# Lumen Illuminate Http Client Request unresolvable dependency

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, post, lumen

I'm trying to store a data via POST method using Laravel\Lumen with Eloquent.
The database I'm using is MySQL.

Heres my CategoriesController.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Request;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Category::all();
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        return response()
            ->json(
                Category::create(['description' => $request->description]),
                201
            );
    }
}
```

Here's my CategoryModel.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['description'];

    public function expense()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Expense::class);
    }
}
```

In my App.php file I've uncommented the lines:

```php
$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();
```

My Web.php file:

```php
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function ($router){
   

    $router->get('categories', 'CategoriesController@index');
    $router->post('categories', 'CategoriesController@create');
});
```

Via Postman I'm sending the following post request:

```json
{
        "description" : "teste"
}
```

After the request was sented I'm having the 500 HTTP Status Response.
The error contains the following StackTrace:

> BindingResolutionException HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

```php
in C:\Fontes\PHP\budget-manager\vendor\illuminate\container\Container.php (line 1053)
     */    protected function unresolvablePrimitive(ReflectionParameter $parameter)
        {
            $message = "Unresolvable dependency resolving [$parameter] in class {$parameter->getDeclaringClass()->getName()}";
            throw new BindingResolutionException($message);
        }
```

Comment: how you call in the controller?

Comment: I found just right now what was causing this trouble. Note that in the CategoriesController file I'm using the `use Illuminate\Http\Client\Request;`. I've swithced it to `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` and after this change I could send the request with no problem

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem.

my VSCode was importing automatically the `use Illuminate\Http\Client\Request` dependency.

After a hard time dedicated to find what was wrong I figured that the correct dependency it's `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`.

Hope that this solution works for those who's having the same problems.